# phtread_kill() Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a list of java threads `top -H -p [java ppid number]` and want to kill certain with pthread_kill() by C call

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main(void)
{
        pthread_kill(23242,SIGKILL);
        return 0;
}
```

Compiling like this

```
sudo gcc ckill.c -o comp -pthread
```

returns

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

What's wrong?

Comment: Let's assume it would work - why would you do that? Purposely making the program / VM fail? I am curious ... Sounds pretty sadistic to me :)

Comment: Somebody showed me that certain user report loads java and kills browser. He asked me to resolve it. I don't have sources...

Comment: Delete it ;) just kidding ... Very interesting way to try and address that problem. I couldn't imagine anything really. Maybe you should start another question with the actual problem in focus?

Comment: Ok) I'll audvocate myself with your reply in face of Somebody

Comment: Please, remove `java` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pthread_kill()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) can send a signal to a thread within the *same process*. And for that reason, it takes a `pthread_t` as an argument, not a PID. So you can't send signals to some java process as you are doing.

If you want to send a signal to any process on the system, have a look at [`kill()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html).

Comment: Thanks. 
kill() kills all java, I need certain leaking thread

Comment: pthreads are not same as the Java threads. If you are looking for some problematic Java threads, then using pthreads to kill/identify seems to be a bit of an overkill. Why not use a simple script to identify the leaking thread?

Comment: I've identified it.. i have two last ideas: kill it via tomcat or in code

Comment: I am not sure why you have to kill it via a C program. Why not use the program `/bin/kill` or the builtin `kill` which most shells provide?

Comment: if you kill smth 'from top -H -p [java ppid number]' it will kill all java not the thread. So googling led me to C funcs: tgkill(), pthread_kill()

I start leaking report in browser and can see the thread wrapped to pid

Comment: There's no safe way to kill a thread from outside. If the process handles signals that's good (you'd able be able to send signals if you know it'll be handled appropriately). Otherwise, you might end killing the whole process. This applies regardless of in which way you attempt to kill externally.

Comment: @Riorita  Did you start that "leaking" thread?  Is it running code that you know what it's doing?  Code that you control, that you wrote?  If not, then killing it isn't going to fix your problem - and is likely to create a lot more problems.  Find *why* the thread is "leaking", and fix **that**.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, I can start this thread to test. I'm admin, it's not my code, tried to resolve it like admin. Thanks, now I see that fixing is the correct way.